# Google maps api and google search provides different lat lang of a place

Tags: laravel, google-maps, curl, google-maps-api-3, geocode

I am trying to get latitude and longitude of a place, however, its returning different value than the value provided by google search.

```
        $url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=".urlencode($request->address).",US&key=API_KEY";
        try {
            $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
            $apiRequest = $client->request('GET', $url);
            $resp = json_decode($apiRequest->getBody());
        } catch (\Exception $re) {
            return response()->json([
                'sts' => -1,
                'message' => $re->getMessage()],
                500);
        }

        $latitude = $resp->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
        $longitude = $resp->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
```

So for testing purpose, I have passed `New York` as the address. It returns

```
[location] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [lat] => 43.2994285
                        [lng] => -74.2179326
                    )
```

However, when I google with keyword `lat long of New York` it returns value

```
40.7128° N, 74.0060° W
```

I don't get why it is returning the difference of `3 degree`, I understand there could be some minor difference like in this [page](https://www.latlong.net/convert-address-to-lat-long.html), however, difference of 3 degree, is quite inconvenient. 
Is there something, I might be missing?

Comment: The difference can come from one using miles and one using kilometers. Have you also set the zoom? This could have some difference also

Comment: that miles and km could be used while calculating distance, however, upto this point I am just trying to get latitude and longitude

Comment: That was not what you asked, you asked why there is a difference between the two

Comment: I have'nt used zoom. Also, I have never heard about that zoom could make the difference in final latitute and longitude values. And, upto this point (getting latitude and longitue) I don't think there is any relation with neither km nor miles.

Comment: I think is because "New York" is not just a city, is also an state. So depending on wich kind of search or properties you use, it will return one thing or another. Or maybe both. It returns you a single result or more than one?.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you have geocoded the address "**New York, US**" in which the geocoder sees as an administrative area or a state. Please see the result in the geocoder tool [here](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3DNew%2520York%252C%2520US) which shows the approximate location `43.299429,-74.217933` for the New York State.

On the other hand, if you geocode the address "[New York, NY, USA](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3DNew%2520York%252C%2520NY%252C%2520USA)", you should get the approximate location `40.712775,-74.005973` which is for New York City which is a locality.

Hope this clarifies it.